# How to get that pretty key name that Blender shows in a keymap button?

Tags: python, interface, keymap

Is there a way to get the complex label that Blender shows for keymap items, when the only thing I have is the key type for that keymap?
That is, getting the "Spacebar" string, when all you have is "SPACE" (like from the `event.type` in a modal handler of a modal operator)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the same displayable key name.
You need to use that "SPACE" string (AKA the event type, [which can be anything from the event type constants](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html#bpy.types.Event.type)), as a key in the dictionary of enum items of the EnumProperty `type` of the bl_rna of the `bpy.types.Event` struct (phew!).

The path to this dictionary is:

`bpy.types.Event.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items`

To be accessed like this from Python (usually inside the `modal()` function of your operator, but not necessarily):

```
>>> eventType = event.type # This is a string. It can be 'SPACE', 'LEFTMOUSE' etc.
>>> enumItem = bpy.types.Event.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items[eventType]
>>> enumItem.name # The displayable key name.
'Spacebar'
```